# How to delete key/value pair if the same value is found in another key/value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a hash and initialized five key/value pairs:

```
my_hash = {}
my_hash[:some_key]  = "hello world"
my_hash[:some_key2] = "apple"
my_hash[:some_key3] = "pear"
my_hash[:some_key4] = "hello world"
my_hash[:some_key5] = "pear"

> my_hash
  => {:some_key=>"hello world", :some_key2=>"apple", :some_key3=>"pear", :some_key4=>"hello world", :some_key5=>"pear"}
```

I want each key/value pair to be unique by its value.  If another key/value pair has a matching `value`, then delete one of these matching key/value pairs (I don't care which key/value pair is ultimately deleted).

So for my example, I want to delete these two key/value pairs because there is already a key/value pair that has that specified `value`.

```
my_hash[:some_key4] = "hello world"
my_hash[:some_key5] = "pear"
```

To reiterate, it would be fine to delete the *other* matching key/value pairs instead. Ultimately, each key/value pair has to be unique by its value:

```
my_hash[:some_key]  = "hello world"
my_hash[:some_key3] = "pear"
```

The returned hash should be:

```
> my_hash
  => {:some_key=>"hello world", :some_key2=>"apple", :some_key3=>"pear"}
```

How can I do this?  I know about `delete_if` but I don't know how to look through the rest of the collection and see if the `value` exists in any of the other key/value pairs.

Comment: It seems that your keys and values are in the wrong order. Values should be the keys :) Then your uniqueness requirement is maintained automatically by the nature of hashmap.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I believe I understand what you are saying.  Ultimately this applies to a rails situation: `@model.errors.full_messages`.  In my scenario it returns a hash with this issue, so I want to delete key/value pairs in order to make them all unique by value.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem. See "[mcve]" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Comment: @theTinMan kind of hard to show my attempt when I explain in the last part of the question "I know about `delete_if` but I don't know how to look through the rest of the collection".  I explain right there that I don't know how to iterate over  a collection within the block of a method called on that collection.  Is this truly worthy of a down vote?

Comment: It's important to understand the goal of Stack Overflow. It's not a "give me an answer to my question" site, it's a "here's a question to help others in the future, along with the associated answer" site. We want to help you, but you have to provide a good question for those in the future to help them. The evidence of effort (searching and code) rules out "give me the codez" questions, where we're expected to code for free. We expect you to help us in the goals for the site since you agreed to do so when you signed up. Does that help explain it? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592

Comment: @theTinMan no that is not clear to me.  It is as if you are saying a person should not ask a question they are trying to figure out.  Nevertheless, on all my questions I usually provide code for what I attempted, but I couldn't find a way to provide code on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, perhaps:

```
my_hash.invert.invert
```

Comment: While clever, this solution would not pass my code review in a real production application.

Comment: Cleverness can often be a smell. If I was going to include this in a production system I would definitely implement it as a refinement with a meaningful name, like `uniq_by_value`

Comment: @Mark, please elaborate.

Comment: @CarySwoveland because it's not immediately apparent what problem it is trying to solve, it would require a comment. Anything that requires explanation is a smell. David's idea of wrapping it with a meaningful name would help.

Comment: @MarkThomas Furthermore, encapsulation of the logic would allow robust testing of any side-effects that might have been assumed, based on the order of the elements for example. You'd want to test whether a Ruby upgrade has suddenly given you the the last/first matching key instead of the first/last (if that matters to you)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array#uniq` and transformations to/from array.

```
my_hash = {
  :some_key=>"hello world", 
  :some_key2=>"apple", 
  :some_key3=>"pear", 
  :some_key4=>"hello world", 
  :some_key5=>"pear",
}

my_hash.to_a # => [[:some_key, "hello world"], [:some_key2, "apple"], [:some_key3, "pear"], [:some_key4, "hello world"], [:some_key5, "pear"]]
my_hash.to_a.uniq(&:last) # => [[:some_key, "hello world"], [:some_key2, "apple"], [:some_key3, "pear"]]
my_hash.to_a.uniq(&:last).to_h # => {:some_key=>"hello world", :some_key2=>"apple", :some_key3=>"pear"}
```

Comment: `uniq_by` is implemented as `Array#uniq` in ruby.
`my_hash.to_a.uniq(&:last).to_h
 => {:some_key=>"hello world", :some_key2=>"apple", :some_key3=>"pear"} `

Comment: @MickeySheu: ah, indeed! I have outdated info about its implementation details :)

Answer (score 2):

Not as concise as David's answer, but this will get the job done:

```
my_hash.delete_if{|k,v| my_hash.values.find_all{|x| x == v}.length > 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer David Aldridge gave, but will keep the first key that has the value

```
my_hash.reduce({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[v] ||= k; memo}.invert
```

Answer (score 0):

As I alluded to in a comment on this question: I asked this question so that I could later apply it to a specific situation in rails: When I called `@some_model.errors.messages`, I was getting back key/value pairs where the value, or the message, was repeated.  I needed to find a way to have unique `errors.messages` by the values.  It was an odd situation, I think due to nested_fields within the form.

Anyways: here was the solution, thanks to help from the other answers:

```
@some_model.errors.messages.each do |attr, msg|
  @some_model.errors.delete(attr) if @some_model.errors.messages.values.flatten.find_all{|x| "#{[x]}" == "#{msg}"}.length > 1
end
```

And with that, I knew that all the messages in the errors hash were unique.